# svg text mask cutting off text

Tags: css, svg

I have been looking for solutions but apparently there a few different ways masks can be used with text so hopefully someone can correct whatever problem I'm having here.

here is the codepen

https://codepen.io/cole-pratt/pen/OJVVzYQ

and here is the code

```css
text {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="texture">
      <image height="400" width="800" xlink:href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.segurohealthandsafety.co.uk%2Fproduct%2Frisk-assessment-method-statement-for-tarmac-planing%2F&psig=AOvVaw291PiCwBSaQHcImwV4v0pK&ust=1581467576139000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCNji7fqfyOcCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAH">
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text x="100" y="100" font-family="arial" mask="url(#texture)">Texture</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

That codepen is a 404. You have unescaped characters in your image URL. The image URL is invalid. If you replace the URL with the texture image I think you're trying to use - everything works fine.

```css
text {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<svg >
  <defs>
    <mask id="texture">
      <image height="400" width="800" xlink:href="https://www.segurohealthandsafety.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Tarmac-Planing-risk-assessment.jpg">
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text x="100" y="100" font-family="arial" mask="url(#texture)">Texture</text>
</svg>
```